# How can i change the paper size in tikzposter?

Tags: geometry, paper-size, tikzposter

Right now the only allowed paper sizes in `tikzposter` are `a0paper`, `a1paper`, or `a2paper`. Is there a way to manually set the size of the poster in inches or other units?

Comment: Did you try `geometry` package?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `tikzposter` class loads `geometry`, so you can use its syntax to specify different paper sizes:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=4in,paperheight=3in}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

10.2cm is 4in and 7.6cm is 3in

Answer (score 14):

This is not enough. `tikzposter` uses `\TP@visibletextwidth` and `\TP@visibletextheight` to compute things like column widths etc., and it's computed from the default page size by the class. So, after you set the paper height and width you also have to say

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{\textwidth-2\TP@innermargin}
\setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{\textheight-2\TP@innermargin}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Finally!  I could not figure out how to stop the columns from running outside the page until finding your answer.

Comment: Where do I need to put this in the document? I get tons of errors when trying to add it after the geometry command.

Comment: It works for me right after the `\geometry` command. Can you post a MWE and the errors you get?