# Columns environment doesn't scale to full paper size tikzposter (using custom paper size)

Tags: tikzposter

I am trying to create my poster using the TikzPoster class. I found this answer that explains how to set custom size: [How can i change the paper size in tikzposter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183219/how-can-i-change-the-paper-size-in-tikzposter). I have set it to 152.4cm by 106.68cm (60in x 42in). But, I have found that the columns environment does not scale to use the full width of the paper, although the title block does scale correctly (I an passing it `0.98\textwidth`).

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[17pt, a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=42in, paperheight=60in}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}

\title{\parbox{0.95\linewidth}{\centering \textbf{My Poster Title}}}

{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2em}
\author
{%
    \begin{tabular}{ c | c | c }
        \textbf{Author 1*} \emph{Author position 1} \hfill & \hfill \textbf{Author 2} \emph{Author position 2} \hfill & \hfill \textbf{Author 3} \emph{Author Position 3} \\
        \texttt{Auth1@univ.edu; Auth1Phone} \hfill & \texttt{Auth2@univ.edu; Auth2Phone} \hfill & \texttt{Auth3@univ.edu; Auth3Phone} \\
    \end{tabular}%
}

\institute
{
    \textbf{Affiliated University and Department}\\
    \vspace*{0.2em}
    Address
}

\titlegraphic
{
    \raisebox{2.25cm}{\includegraphics[width=11cm,height=3cm]{/Poster/Logo1.png}}
    \hfill 
    \includegraphics[width=7.5cm,height=7.5cm]{/Poster/Logo2.png}
}

\makeatletter
\def\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance{-7.5cm}
\settitle
{
    \centering
    \vbox
    {
        \@titlegraphic \\ [\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance] 
        \centering
        \color{titlefgcolor}
        {\bfseries \huge \sc \@title \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\LARGE \@author \par}
        \vspace*{1.2em}
        {\LARGE \@institute}
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \maketitle[width=0.98\textwidth]
    \block{First}{Check Span}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.2}
            \block{ABSTRACT}
            {
                asdf
            }
            \block{INTRODUCTION}
            {}
            \block{DATA DESCRIPTIONS}
            {
                \innerblock{Data 1}{qaz}
                \innerblock{Data 2}{wsx}
                \innerblock{Data 3}{edc}
            }
        \column{0.2}
            \block{ISSUES}
            {
                lkjh
            }
            \block{SOLUTIONS}
            {
                123456789
            }
        \column{0.6}
            \begin{subcolumns}
                \subcolumn{0.5}
                    \block{Case Study I}
                    {
                        qwerty
                    }
                \subcolumn{0.5}
                    \block{Case Study II}
                    {
                        uiop
                    }
            \end{subcolumns}
            \block{COMPARISON RESULTS}
            {
                zxcvbnm
            }
    \end{columns}
\end{document}
```

And here is what it produces:

[image: What the code produces]

But what I would rather want is for the columns to span the whole width of the paper, all the way till where the title box starts and ends. As you can see in the code, I am not changing any margins, so all values are default.

I have also looked through the tikzposter class file, and have not managed to find the cause of the problem. But today is my third day with LaTeX, so I have a pretty small idea about what I should be looking for in the first place. I tried to display the value of `\TP@visibletextwidth` in one of the blocks of the poster, unsuccessfully. I would appreciate any help! Thanks a lot.

Please let me know if you need any additional details. (I know my code is uncommented, but this is just my 3rd day, and this is a rough script. Sorry about that.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After issuing

```
\geometry{paperwidth=42in, paperheight=60in}
```

you have to recalculate `\TP@visibletextwidth` and `\TP@visibletextheight`. So, after that line, add

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{\textwidth-2\TP@innermargin}
\setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{\textheight-2\TP@innermargin}
\makeatother
```

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove this line in your document
\documentclass[17pt, a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\geometry{paperwidth=42in, paperheight=60in}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{\textwidth-2\TP@innermargin}
\setlength{\TP@visibletextheight}{\textheight-2\TP@innermargin}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[space]{grffile}

\title{\parbox{0.95\linewidth}{\centering \textbf{My Poster Title}}}

{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2em}
\author
{%
    \begin{tabular}{ c | c | c }
        \textbf{Author 1*} \emph{Author position 1} \hfill & \hfill \textbf{Author 2} \emph{Author position 2} \hfill & \hfill \textbf{Author 3} \emph{Author Position 3} \\
        \texttt{Auth1@univ.edu; Auth1Phone} \hfill & \texttt{Auth2@univ.edu; Auth2Phone} \hfill & \texttt{Auth3@univ.edu; Auth3Phone} \\
    \end{tabular}%
}

\institute
{
    \textbf{Affiliated University and Department}\\
    \vspace*{0.2em}
    Address
}

\titlegraphic
{
    \raisebox{2.25cm}{\includegraphics[width=11cm,height=3cm]{/Poster/Logo1.png}}
    \hfill
    \includegraphics[width=7.5cm,height=7.5cm]{/Poster/Logo2.png}
}

\makeatletter
\def\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance{-7.5cm}
\settitle
{
    \centering
    \vbox
    {
        \@titlegraphic \\ [\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance]
        \centering
        \color{titlefgcolor}
        {\bfseries \huge \sc \@title \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\LARGE \@author \par}
        \vspace*{1.2em}
        {\LARGE \@institute}
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \maketitle[width=0.98\textwidth]
    \block{First}{Check Span}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{0.2}
            \block{ABSTRACT}
            {
                asdf
            }
            \block{INTRODUCTION}
            {}
            \block{DATA DESCRIPTIONS}
            {
                \innerblock{Data 1}{qaz}
                \innerblock{Data 2}{wsx}
                \innerblock{Data 3}{edc}
            }
        \column{0.2}
            \block{ISSUES}
            {
                lkjh
            }
            \block{SOLUTIONS}
            {
                123456789
            }
        \column{0.6}
            \begin{subcolumns}
                \subcolumn{0.5}
                    \block{Case Study I}
                    {
                        qwerty
                    }
                \subcolumn{0.5}
                    \block{Case Study II}
                    {
                        uiop
                    }
            \end{subcolumns}
            \block{COMPARISON RESULTS}
            {
                zxcvbnm
            }
    \end{columns}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

and the paper size is the correct one:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much @karlkoeller.