# Blocks overflow the poster using tikzposter

Tags: posters, tikzposter

[How can i change the paper size in tikzposter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183219/how-can-i-change-the-paper-size-in-tikzposter)

told me how to set the paper size to the one I need. There is a problem though, the blocks overflow the set size:

[image: blocks overflow here]

My minimal LaTeX file is

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\geometry{paperwidth=74cm,paperheight=121cm}

\title{Super-scientific poster}
\author{Smart Author}
\institute{Famous University}
\usetheme{Default}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}

\column{0.5}
\block{Dummy}{text}

\column{0.5}
\block{Dummy2}{text2}

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

What do I need to let `tikzposter` `block`s know the poster width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to adjust the `textwidth` and `textheight` suitable for the paper dimensions. To do that add the following lines to your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{73cm}
\setlength{ \TP@visibletextheight}{120cm}
\makeatother
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

%\geometry{paperwidth=841mm,paperheight=1189mm}   %% aopaper sizes
\geometry{paperwidth=74cm,paperheight=121cm}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\TP@visibletextwidth}{73cm}
\setlength{ \TP@visibletextheight}{120cm}
\makeatother

\title{Super-scientific poster}
\author{Smart Author}
\institute{Famous University}
\usetheme{Default}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{columns}

\column{0.5}
\block{Dummy}{text}

\column{0.5}
\block{Dummy2}{text2}

\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

[image]