# change paper size of Elena's custom tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter

I am using Elena's tikzposter (http://www.inf.unibz.it/~ebotoeva/fancytikzposter.html) and would like to change the poster size to A1, not A0. Is there a way to do this? I tried changing the geometry, but the font does not scale with the changes. Everything becomes out of place. Is there a way to scale it accordingly? I have not changed much from the template, just added my text and some figures as well as the following:

```
\setmargin{1}
\setblockspacing{.85}
\setblocktitleheight{1}
\usetemplate{N3}
\setheaddrawingheight{10}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=59.4cm, paperheight=84.1cm]{geometry}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is a generic solution 
 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183219/how-can-i-change-the-paper-size-in-tikzposter

Answer (score 2):

This is surprisingly easy:

Instead of using `\documentclass[a0paper]{tikzposter}` use`\documentclass[a1paper]{tikzposter}`.